# Is that we can send the multipart/form-data till 2GB by using rest api in apex

Tags: apex, rest-api, apexrest, restresource

Is that multipart message is available in RestAPI in Apex 2021 to send the large files(till 2GB) from source org to target org??

Answer (score 0):

Apex can't handle data this large. You will need some kind of external ETL (Extract, Transform, Load) tool, or custom software, in order to migrate files of this size. By the way, you're looking for "chunked" upload, not "multipart message." The former is an HTTP header that allows for resuming uploads, the latter is used for posting forms with binary content.